# Как записать все значения в csv файл?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, csv

Пишу такой парсер, но в файл записывается только одна строка, не разделённая по столбцам, хотя условие all вроде бы стоит. Данные беру только из тега "р" потому что в других блоках, например название неполное. Как мне записать в csv файл все результаты парсинга, разделённые по колонкам?

```py
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs
import os
import lxml
import csv
from csv import writer

f = codecs.open("ZHVACHKA.html", 'r', 'utf-8')
html = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
products = soup.findAll("div", class_="tovar")
products_json = [products]

with open("Products.csv", "a", encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Product Name', 'Price'])
    for product in products:
        try:
            product_name = product.find("p")  # вытащил значение из тега по атрибуту
            product_price = product.find("p")  # вытащил цену
            #print(f'{product_name["name"]}, {product_price["price"]}')
            writer.writerows([[f'{product_name["name"]}, {product_price["price"]}']])
        except Exception as ex:
            print()
        break
```

Кусок html прилагаю:

```html
<div class="tovar">
  <div class="image-tovar" tid="DpR5YsiqGI" name_eng="zhevatelnaya-rezinka-exit-s-myatoy-bez-sahara-1">  
  </div>                                 
  <div class="tovar-schet" tid="DpR5YsiqGI">
    <div id="minus" tid="DpR5YsiqGI" price="32.9">−</div>      
    <div class="kol-vo" id="kol-voDpR5YsiqGI">0</div>
    <p id="plus" tid="DpR5YsiqGI" price="32.9" name="Жевательная резинка EXIT С мятой без сахара 1/20шт(8699449031342)" magazine_sort="jKZIRdGMXN">+</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tovar-name" tid="DpR5YsiqGI" name_eng="zhevatelnaya-rezinka-exit-s-myatoy-bez-sahara-1">Жевательная резинка EXIT
С мятой без сахар...</div>
  <div class="tovar-price">32.9 руб.</div>
</div>
                            
<div class="tovar">
  <div class="image-tovar" tid="bS8oh6XnQa" name_eng="zhevatelnaya-rezinka-dirol-colors-xxl-19gr-ass">  
  </div>                                 
  <div class="tovar-schet" tid="bS8oh6XnQa">
    <div id="minus" tid="bS8oh6XnQa" price="54.9">−</div>      
    <div class="kol-vo" id="kol-vobS8oh6XnQa">0</div>
    <p id="plus" tid="bS8oh6XnQa" price="54.9" name="Жевательная резинка DIROL COLORS XXL 19гр Ассорти фруктовых вкусов 1/18шт(57030852)" magazine_sort="jKZIRdGMXN">+</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tovar-name" tid="bS8oh6XnQa" name_eng="zhevatelnaya-rezinka-dirol-colors-xxl-19gr-ass">Жевательная резинка
DIROL COLORS XXL 19гр ...</div>
  <div class="tovar-price">54.9 руб.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

У Вас

> но в файл записывается только одна строка

срабатывает **break** после записи первой строки и код завершает работу, а

> строка, не разделённая по столбцам

не корректно форматируются строки.
Поправил Вам код, сейчас вроде всё записывается как вы хотите:

```
...
    for product in products:
        try:
            product_name = product.find("p")  # вытащил значение из тега по атрибуту
            product_price = product.find("p")  # вытащил цену
            print(f'{product_name["name"]}, {product_price["price"]}')
            writer.writerows([[f'{product_name["name"]}', f'{product_price["price"]}']])
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
...
```

Содержание Products.csv:

```
Product Name,Price
Жевательная резинка EXIT С мятой без сахара 1/20шт(8699449031342),32.9
Жевательная резинка DIROL COLORS XXL 19гр Ассорти фруктовых вкусов 1/18шт(57030852),54.9
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!))